Convert scanned pdf to Excel without changing placement of data
I have around 45 pdf's, of varying length which are scanned in. The data is pretty uniform, the content is tabular with the headers being the same for all the documents. I would like to transfer them to Excel, and carry out some analysis. The issue is, some of the entries have blank entries, some are multi line. I would like a programmatic solution which I can use to import multiple documents without changing placement of the data.
Here is an example of what the table looks like: Every date is a separate entry.



EVENT DATE
EVENT ID
QUERY
OPERATION
SOURCE




01/01/2001
ABC_AA 0000

NETFLIX
ONLINE



_A1234_46789





02/01/2001
ABC_BB 0000

DISNEY
MEETING



_A1234_46789






ABC_CC 0000






_A1234_46789





03/01/2001



ONLINE



This is the code I have attempted so far:
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
import pytesseract
import pandas as pd
import re

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = TESSERACT_PATH

# Path to the PDF file
pdf_path = PDF_PATH

# Convert PDF pages to images (skip the first page)
images = convert_from_path(pdf_path, first_page=2)

def remove_footer(lines):
    footer_keywords = [FOOTER]
    return [line for line in lines if not any(keyword in line for keyword in footer_keywords)]

data = []
# Iterate over each image
for img in images:
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)

    # Split the text into lines
    lines = text.splitlines()

    # Remove footer lines
    filtered_lines = remove_footer(lines)

    # Process the lines to extract table data
    row = []
    for line in filtered_lines:
        if line.strip():
            row.append(line.strip())
        elif row:
            data.append(row)
            row = []

    if row:
        data.append(row)

# Convert list of rows into DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Handle blank values
df = df.replace('', None)

# Show DataFrame
print(df)

There are a couple of things wrong with the code.

Multi-line entries are an issue - text that is on the second and third line are filling in the values for empty cells in the column.
Blank spaces are not being respected. If there is a blank space on the 4th column, it is filled with the entry in the 5th column. This means the last few columns are now blank, even though in the original image that is not the case.
Columns are being put in wherever there is a space. I have no idea what else to do it as, as the data isn't necessarily uniform.




EVENT
DATE
EVENT
ID
QUERY
OPERATION
SOURCE




01/01/2001
ABC_AA
0000
NETFLIX
ONLINE
_A1234_46789



02/01/2001
ABC_BB
0000
DISNEY
MEETING
_A1234_46789



ABC_CC
0000
_A1234_46789






03/01/2001
ONLINE








Would anyone happen to know how to keep it relatively the same as what's on the table? The closest I've come so far is excel image to data, but it isn't possible to use that considering I need to do it for 100's of pages!

Hello, I assume by Tabula, you mean: https://tabula.technology/
This doesn't work on scanned documents - only text based PDF's. Mine are scanned in.

As I mentioned in the question, I have been using an OCR. What I would like to do is to retain the position on the table.
